# How do I make independent API's?

Tags: python, json, api, flask, request

I'm far from being an expert on the topic and my question might even make no sense, but I'm trying to make an app that gathers data from a server I made. There's a Python script I made that logs into a website and scrapes data from it. When you make a GET request to the API, the Python functions get called and the data is put on a server for the app to take. Thing is: whenever a user makes a GET request (or even a POST request, to send the credentials needed for the Python script to log in), the server changes for every user. For example, if a user posts his credentials, the dictionary "credentials" is changed for everyone and if a second user posts his credentials at the same time, the dictionary might get the wrong values for one of the two users. Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import backend as b

app = Flask(__name__)
credentials = dict()
subjectNames = ['Italiano', 'Inglese', 'Filosofia', 'Storia', 'Matematica', 'Informatica', 'Fisica', 'Scienze', 'Arte', 'Educazione Fisica']

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def getCredentials():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.get_json(force=True).get('username')
        password = request.get_json(force=True).get('password')
        credentials['username'] = username
        credentials['password'] = password
        return jsonify({'credentials': credentials})


@app.route ('/creds', methods=['GET'])
def creds():
    return jsonify({'credentials': credentials})

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = str(request.args['query'])
        if query == 'marks':
            d = {}
            m = b.getFullMarks(b.login(credentials['username'], credentials['password']))
            for i in range(len(subjectNames)):
                d[subjectNames[i]] = m[i]
            return jsonify(d)
        elif query == 'names':
            d = {}
            m = b.getNames(b.login(credentials['username'], credentials['password']))
            for i in range(len(subjectNames)):
                d[subjectNames[i]] = m[i]
            return jsonify(d)
        elif query == 'calendar':
            d = {}
            m = b.calendar(b.login(credentials['username'], credentials['password']))
            d['Calendar'] = m
            return jsonify(d)
        elif query == 'badge':
            d = {}
            m = b.badge(b.login(credentials['username'], credentials['password']))
            d['Badge'] = m
            return jsonify(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The global `credentials = dict()` is a big problem for webapps. You want to use [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or similar, to be handling this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that you keep all of the credentials in memory, and if the server crashes, you lost everything.

You can't use a dictionary to do as you want, as you already know, a dictionary can only hold a single representation of the same key (in our case, 'username'). so when a 2nd user calls the `/login` endpoint, you're overwriting the previous one and vice versa.

As mentioned before, most applications will generate a token on a successful login, and will send it back to the calling user.
The user will add it as a header on his upcoming requests, this allows the service to identify the calling user, and do whatever it needs.

You can look for existing implementations, or do something on your own.
but eventually, you'll need to map the token to the user, e.g:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def getCredentials():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.get_json(force=True).get('username')
        password = request.get_json(force=True).get('password')
        token = generate_token_for_user(username, password)
        credentials[token] = {'username': username, 'password': password}
        return jsonify({'token': token})
```

and in the api call:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    token = request.headers['Authorization'] # assuming you're using this for your token
    creds = credentials.get(token)
    d = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = str(request.args['query'])
        if query == 'marks':
            m = b.getFullMarks(b.login(creds['username'], creds['password']))
            for i in range(len(subjectNames)):
                d[subjectNames[i]] = m[i]
            return jsonify(d)
        elif query == 'names':
            m = b.getNames(b.login(creds['username'], creds['password']))
            for i in range(len(subjectNames)):
                d[subjectNames[i]] = m[i]
            return jsonify(d)
        elif query == 'calendar':
            m = b.calendar(b.login(creds['username'], creds['password']))
            d['Calendar'] = m
            return jsonify(d)
        elif query == 'badge':
            m = b.badge(b.login(creds['username'], creds['password']))
            d['Badge'] = m
            return jsonify(d)
```

Offcourse, that maintaining a token lifecycle is a bit more complex, need to invalidate the token after a period of time, and you'll need to validate it on every request (usually with a middleware), but this is the concept.

Comment: So you're saying that both password and username should be in the headers? Also, if you feel like it, could you please point me to an explanation on how to implement headers? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well not exactly, the common way is to represent your user name and password via a one way hash or token, and send the token in one of the headers.
The user logs in with the user name and password
the server authenticates the user, and provides him with a token to make API requests
on every API request the client sends the token in a designated header, and the server verifies the token is valid.

you can read more about headers here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers